# Python subprocess: How can I execute a sub-process of a process in python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to be able to run the following command:

```
sh -c "python -c "import sys;sys.platform""
```

however I am failing to do so with subprocess

I have tried the following but

```
subprocess.check_output(["sh", "-c", ["python", "-c",  '"import sys; print sys.platform"']])
```

I get the following output:

```
sh: python-cimport: command not found
File "<string>", line 1
    "import
          ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are getting tangled up with each other.  Try:

```
sh -c 'python -c "import sys; print sys.platform"'
```

Or, if you're trying to call it from inside another python program, perhaps you mean to say this...

```
subprocess.check_output(['python', '-c', 'import sys; print sys.platform'])
```

Or is there a great reason for trying to nest this inside a shell?

Comment: The reason is I am running this under cygwin and the script which I am about to call with subprocess is incompatible with windows and msys/mingw. I wanted to know whether or not the python used is cygwin based or not.

Answer (score 2):

In the order of preference (how to print the platform info):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import platform

print(platform.platform())
```

If you want to run it as a separate process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.check_call([sys.executable or 'python', '-m', 'platform'])
```

If you want to run in a shell:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call('python -m platform', shell=True)
```

On POSIX, it is equvalent to:

```
subprocess.check_call(['/bin/sh', '-c', 'python -m platform'])
```

Your specific command:

```
subprocess.check_call(['/bin/sh', '-c', 
                       "python -c 'import sys; print(sys.platform)'"])
```